# Highcharts - Highstock "inputEditDataFormat" breaking input

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I am building a highstock chart at my company and currently I'm having the following issue:

I need to change the rangeSelector input fields to german locale format. For example: 25.06.2016

But I noticed that, as soon as I change the date format in the option "inputEditDateFormat" it just doesn't work anymore. I'm not sure if the chart just mixes up the month and day, but it doesn't do what it's supposed to.

I've made a fiddle to give you an insight on my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/G7azG/34/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        "colors": [
          "#fedd00",
          "#22b6ae",
          "#c0263c",
          "#136e6c",
          "#e2a297"
        ],
        "legend": {
          "align": "left",
          "adjustChartSize": true,
          "navigation": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "enabled": false
        },
        "rangeSelector": {
          "selected": 4,
          "inputDateFormat": "%d.%m.%Y",
          "inputEditDateFormat": "%d.%m.%Y" // <-- blame this fool
        },
        "yAxis": {
          "labels": {},
          "plotLines": [
            {
              "value": 0,
              "width": 2,
              "color": "silver"
            }
          ]
        },
        "plotOptions": {
          "series": {
            "compare": "percent",
            "showInNavigator": true,
            "lineWidth": 3
          }
        },
        "tooltip": {
          "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} €/t</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>",
          "valueDecimals": 2,
          "split": true
        },
        "series": [
          {
            "data": [
              [
                1136073600000,
                72.9
              ],
              [
                1138752000000,
                73.6
              ],
              [
                1141171200000,
                74.2
              ],
              [
                1143849600000,
                75
              ],
              [
                1146441600000,
                75.3
              ],
              [
                1149120000000,
                75.8
              ],
              [
                1151712000000,
                77.3
              ],
              [
                1154390400000,
                78.6
              ],
              [
                1157068800000,
                80.4
              ],
              [
                1159660800000,
                82.8
              ],
              [
                1162339200000,
                83.6
              ],
              [
                1164931200000,
                86.5
              ],
              [
                1167609600000,
                86.8
              ],
              [
                1170288000000,
                84.5
              ],
              [
                1172707200000,
                82.5
              ],
              [
                1175385600000,
                77.6
              ],
              [
                1177977600000,
                76.5
              ],
              [
                1180656000000,
                76.1
              ],
              [
                1183248000000,
                76.2
              ],
              [
                1185926400000,
                76.2
              ],
              [
                1188604800000,
                77.4
              ],
              [
                1191196800000,
                81.1
              ],
              [
                1193875200000,
                83.7
              ],
              [
                1196467200000,
                83.6
              ],
              [
                1199145600000,
                83.9
              ],
              [
                1201824000000,
                81.6
              ],
              [
                1204329600000,
                75.3
              ],
              [
                1207008000000,
                67.6
              ],
              [
                1209600000000,
                68
              ],
              [
                1212278400000,
                68.2
              ]
            ],
            "visible": true,
            "name": "Rundholz AT"
          }
        ]
});
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to morganfree I got this working. I just needed to use the `inputDateParser` function like so:

```
rangeSelector: {
    inputDateFormat: "%d.%m.%Y",
    inputEditDateFormat: "%d.%m.%Y",
    inputDateParser: function (value) {
        value = value.split('.');
        console.log(value);
        return Date.UTC(
           parseInt(value[2]),
           parseInt(value[1] - 1),
           parseInt(value[0])
        );
    }
}
```

Cheers;;

Comment: you are saying that you are not able to edit the date part.

Comment: @Nair Athul
Sorry, I meant that it doesn't behave the way it should anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs [inputEditDateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.inputEditDateFormat)

> ... This must be a format that is recognized by JavaScript Date.parse.

You need to parse the date with [inputDateParser](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.inputDateParser).

Comment: You nailed it. I don't know how I missed that part, but it was just what I needed. Thanks a bunch!